# How can I prevent text overlap between two divs?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid and which row contains:

```
LastName, FirstName
IDNumber
```

However, sometimes the last name and first name are long so it ends up on the second line where the ID number is and it covers the ID number.

```
LastName,
FirstName
IDNumber
```

But First Name covers ID Number.

I set ID Number to have a `margin-top:12px;` to fix the issue but for rows that don't have that problem there is big padding between the two fields. How can I best fix this?

Here's some of the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HexaPod.Models.person>()
    .Name("PersonGrid")
    .ClientRowTemplate("<tr style='height:16px; vertical-align: central;'>" +
        "<td style=\"text-align:left;width:100% !important; \">" +
        "<div style='margin-bottom:5px; clear:both; height:11px;' class=\"type-style-value-emphasized\">#if(LastName != null){#" +
        "#=LastName#" +
        "#}#" +
        "#if(LastName != null && FirstName !=null){#" + 
        ", " +
        "#}#"+
        "#if(FirstName != null){#" +
        " #=FirstName#" +
        "#}#</div>" +
        "<div style='margin-bottom:5px;clear: both; margin-top:12px;' class='type-style-paragraph'>#=IdNumber#</div></td>" +
        "</tr>")
```

Comment: You could set a padding on the LastName/FirstName elements so that the container will size according to content. Do you have a set width or a max-width?  You could set the names to white-space: nowrap; so they don't wrap to a second line, but it depends on how much width you have.

Comment: @JustinBreiland, I can do white-space nowrap but I have a set width for my grid. In order to have them fit, I need to add a horizontal scroll bar. Is there a way I can do this without adding a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: If showing the whole name isn't super important you could truncate it. This would display it on one line but would hide a portion of the name that extended beyond the width. In addition, you could include the name in the title so people can hover over it and still get the whole name.

Comment: good idea. I did that, I just have one problem. How do I resize my hover label width to resize to the text I have truncated?

Comment: Is it truncated in the hover?

Comment: no, it's the full name but there's extra space (almost a full word length) after the text. So I just want to resize the hover window to wrap around the text inside.

Comment: Since you added the title attribute, you style it using the selector [type=title]  and then try playing with the width.  Such as [type=title] { width: auto;}  I would try setting its padding and margin to 0 to see if any browser styles are causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was set Max-Width: 270px and it worked:

```
max-width: 270px;display:inherit;
```

inside:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HexaPod.Models.person>()
    .Name("PersonGrid")
    .ClientRowTemplate("<tr style='height:16px; vertical-align: central;'>" +
        "<td style=\"text-align:left;width:100% !important; \">" +
        "<div style='margin-bottom:5px; clear:both; height:11px;max-width: 270px;display:inherit;' class=\"type-style-value-emphasized\">#if(LastName != null){#" +
        "#=LastName#" +
        "#}#" +
        "#if(LastName != null && FirstName !=null){#" + 
        ", " +
        "#}#"+
        "#if(FirstName != null){#" +
        " #=FirstName#" +
        "#}#</div>" +
        "<div style='margin-bottom:5px;clear: both; margin-top:12px;' class='type-style-paragraph'>#=IdNumber#</div></td>" +
        "</tr>")
```